# map.items is not function how do I solve this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to map all items but it says `map.items` is not a function. How can I solve this problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vivHg.png)

Comment: then maybe items is not an array, map only works on arrays. can you post the code?

Comment: Please post the code!

Comment: If it is supposed to be an array, it might be trying to do the map before the data is available. so basically null.map or undefined.map. Throw in a short circuit if you're waiting for ItemList to populate. ItemList && ItemList.map(e=>//dostuff)

Answer (score 0):

The .map function is only available on an array. Thinking that this is the right answer since the picture that you attached has the object `ItemList`